Error when i run python script to open CANoe config file
When I run this script named main.py bellow to load CANoe cfg file
from py_canoe import CANoe

canoe_inst = CANoe()
canoe_inst.open(canoe_cfg=r'C:xx.cfg')

i received error and CANoe is opened but without desired cfg file.
PS C:\Users\dimange> & C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c:/xx/main.py"
2024-05-10 18:14:25,876 [CANOE_LOG] [INFO ] Dispatched Vector CANoe Application 17.3.91
2024-05-10 18:14:26,270 [CANOE_LOG] [INFO ] CANoe cfg "Modified" parameter set to False to avoid error.
2024-05-10 18:14:26,271 [CANOE_LOG] [INFO ] CANoe cfg "C:xx.cfg" found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xx\from py_canoe import CANoe.py", line 4, in <module>
    canoe_inst.open(canoe_cfg=r'C:xx.cfg')
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py_canoe.py", line 56, in open
    self.application.open(path=canoe_cfg, auto_save=auto_save, prompt_user=prompt_user)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py_canoe_utils\application.py", line 176, in open
    self.com_obj.Open(path, auto_save, prompt_user)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.12\7F31DEB0-5BCC-11D3-8562-00105A3E017Bx0x1x73.py", line 700, in Open

When i run the script second time with already opened CANoe , then missing error and the desired cfg file is loaded.
2024-05-10 18:19:45,720 [CANOE_LOG] [INFO ] Dispatched Vector CANoe Application 17.3.91
2024-05-10 18:19:45,724 [CANOE_LOG] [INFO ] CANoe cfg "Modified" parameter set to False to avoid error.
2024-05-10 18:19:45,724 [CANOE_LOG] [INFO ] CANoe cfg "C:xx.cfg" found.
2024-05-10 18:19:51,882 [CANOE_LOG] [INFO ] loaded CANoe config "C:xx.cfg"

Why i get this error when i run the script with closed CANoe?

Hello! Are you sure that C:xx.cfg is a correct path? May be you meant C:/xx.cfg? Try changing it to C:/xx.cfg

yes , when i paste this path directly in cmd prompt the cfg file is opened. I tried this way and the result is the same
